# Kotlin - Set layoutDirection to linearlayout error binding

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, data-binding, binding

I have implemented data binding in xml and I want to set layoutDirection to my linearlayout, but it causes error like below.

> Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layoutDirection='@{type.equalsIgnoreCase("sell") ? "rtl" : "ltr" }'
        android:baselineAligned="false"></Linearlayout>
```

> This is the error
> [image: The error binding problem]

Comment: post full error and full layout file

Comment: instead of passing the string to the android:layoutDirection we need to pass the LayoutDirection

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BindingAdapter` for this use case:

```
@BindingAdapter("changeLayoutDirection")
fun changeLayoutDirection(layout: LinearLayout, direction: String) {
     
  // Write your code here for direction change

}
```

In your `xml`, add this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        changeLayoutDirection="@{type}"
        android:baselineAligned="false"></Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import `LayoutDirection` (`android:layoutDirection` expecting the `LayoutDirection`) instead of passing the String to the layout direction.

```
<import type="android.util.LayoutDirection"/>
```

change the XML `android:layoutDirection` into this

```
android:layoutDirection='@{type.equalsIgnoreCase("sell") ? LayoutDirection.RTL : LayoutDirection.RTL }'
```